# MySQL AS Statement generating an error

Tags: mysql

I am working through Murach MySQL book and I can't get one of the exercises to run from Chapter 3 and I have no idea what's wrong. The discount_amount column is causing:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'list_price' in 'field list'
```

Well that's why I used AS. Does anyone see what's wrong with my code?

```
SELECT product_name,
   list_price,
   discount_percent,
   list_price*discount_percent AS discount_amount,
   list_price-discount_amount AS discount_price,
   ROUND(discount_amount, 2),
   ROUND(discount_price, 2)
FROM products
ORDER BY discount_price DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to do the calculation again in the ROUND

```
SELECT product_name,
   list_price,
   discount_percent,
   list_price*discount_percent AS discount_amount,
   list_price-discount_amount AS discount_price,
   ROUND(list_price*discount_percent, 2),
   ROUND(list_price-discount_amount, 2)
FROM products
ORDER BY discount_price DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same error. This totally makes sense and I really wanted this to work.

Comment: @lioness What is list_price?

Comment: I got it! SELECT product_name,
   list_price,
   discount_percent,
   list_price * discount_percent AS discount_amount,
   list_price - (list_price * discount_percent) AS discount_price,
   ROUND(list_price * discount_percent, 2),
   ROUND(list_price - (list_price * discount_percent), 2)
FROM products
ORDER BY discount_price DESC
LIMIT 5;

Comment: Great! glad you could get it working! almost had it :)